# Append li items with For Loop in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, append

I'm having the biggest brainfart ever right now...

I need to append `i` amount of slides (which can be blank), but they have to have a specific classes for the internal divs, and a specific ID consisting of `i` in the slides name.

```
<ul class="bjqs"><!-- Target This -->

<li id="slide0"><!-- Append these -->
    <div class="center"><!-- Append these -->
        <span class="author"></span><!-- Append these -->
        <span class="time"></span><!-- Append these -->
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div><!-- Append these -->
</li>
<li id="slide1"><!-- Append these -->
    <div class="center"><!-- Append these -->
        <span class="author"></span><!-- Append these -->
        <span class="time"></span><!-- Append these -->
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</li>
<li id="slide2">... etc
</ul>
```

Perhaps a basic `for loop` would work...?

```
    var slideCount = 20;
    for(var i = slideCount-1;i>=0;i--){
        $('ul.bjqs').after('<li id="slide'+i+'"><div class="center"><span class="author"></span><span class="time"></span></div><div class="image"></div></li>');
    }
```

(Well, it DOES work... but is there a cleaner way?)

Comment: Look into templating [event the basic feature granted by underscore.js would do].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the need and how you prefer to do it.

If you have already a slide at the moment you need to create the others, you can use `clone` method :

```
var slideCount = 20;
for(var i = slideCount-1;i>=0;i--){
    $('ul.bjqs').after($('#slide0').clone().attr('id', 'slide'+i));
}
```

[Here is the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Else, your method is not so bad. I personally don't like to output html with js like this, since you will have several files to maintain if you got to change your layout (at least html and js file). A good way to do could be to clone (see above) an hidden empty slide at the beginning, and then delete it after the generation of others.

Comment: That doesn't appear to append the children divs and spans with the appropriate classes.

Comment: you should be able to run with the answer he's given you and build on it. @NicholasHazel

Comment: What is the problem ? Normally, clone performs a deep copy of the element, the only things not copied are the dynamics attributes/properties (events, values ...). I added the documentation link to my answer.

Comment: if you make a hidden `div` as a template with all the children and attributes then you could just clone it. @NicholasHazel

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I didn't assume that it would also clone all of the children. Thanks a ton!

Comment: My pleasure! BTW, have you noticed that you are generating your slides in descendant order? I mean, for example with 20 slides, you will have something like slide20, slide19, slide18... Is this what you want? Also, if this answer suits you, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I did notice that! Actually, it was intentional :-) The way the JSON is structured is a bit peculiar (it's a new API they're still testing with internally at my company). I had to do a few tweaks (like not removing the template_clone caused the whole thing to break, but everything is running perfectly now. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner way would be to use a two-way binding library like [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="slide in slides" id="slide{{$index}}">
<div class="center">
   <span class="author">{{slide.author}}</span>
   <span class="time">{{slide.time}}</span>
</div>
<div class="image"></div>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.slides=[{author:"Chris",time:"Tues"},{author:"Owen",time:"Wed"}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this won't work for my use case. (I am importing and cycling through a very large JSON file and am running additional scripts to filter through the object.

Comment: I work with large json repsonses in angular all the time. If you want to filter, I'd combine angular with lodash (http://lodash.com/), a very good and performant library to work with collections.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. We are currently utilizing Angular to create a persistent workflow. :-) Not familiar with lodash, but will definitely research. We have MUCH more in the json file than necessary, and I have to filter the results accordingly in JS. Just forgot syntax for a second :-P